# firebase Filters and pagination

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to make a searchable list of posts saves at firebase so i have my firebse db like this

```
{
"post": {
    "postId": {
        "title": "bla bla bla",
        "date": "1/1/2015"
    },
    "postId2": {
        "title": "bla bla bla",
        "date": "2/1/2015"
    }
}}
```

Now I want to filter by title, only post that their title starts with "bla bla" and then do paging and sort by date so I made this code:

```
 var posts=new Firebase(URL + "/post");
 posts=posts.orderByChild("title").startAt("bla bla").endAt("bla bla"+"z");//this will only show posts that starts with bla bla
 posts=posts.orderByChild("date").startAt(10).limitToFirst(10);//this will filter and show only the second page
 posts.on("value", function (raw_data) {
      //showing the results and more
 });
```

each of the queries works but when i put them together i get an error

> Query.orderByChild: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls.

How can I do it?
I prefer not too use my own server and copy the data to my server and do it there

Comment: best. question. ever.

Comment: .endAt('bla bla~') would be better as your current search would exclude many matches like 'bla blaze'). Now, perhaps more importantly, is why? It sounds like you're trying to implement rudimentary search. If so, I'd encourage [a real search tool](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html) instead. There's a reason more people search google rather than any websites' built in search tools.

Comment: Thank you, I'll use the ~ trick, but the "real search tool" is ElasticSearch that need to run on my own server it my server can't scale too much

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do this but here's one way.

Place a date query inside the results of the post query. Conceptually:

```
var posts=new Firebase(URL + "/post");
posts=posts.orderByChild("title").startAt("bla bla").endAt("bla bla"+"z");
posts.on("value", function (raw_data) {
     //now craft a date query using the results from the posts query
     //  or, it could be filtered in code
});
```

Comment: If i do this the second filter will run on the client size, isn't it? so it will fail with too much posts

Comment: The initial question was that you wanted to query by title, and then page and sort by date. A title is generally not a lot of data so it really depends on the size of your dataset and/or the data within each set.